# Readonly property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: typescript

Creating a class like:

```
class myProps {
  public readonly val1: boolean;

  constructor(val1?: boolean) {
    val1 != undefined ? this.val1 = val1 : val1 = true;
  }
}
```

I would expect that his is ok, as inside the constructor (unlike the error claims) val1 is always set to a value. however I get this error (inside the IDE) on the readonly attribute val1:

> Property 'val1' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in
> the constructor.

Why is this and how would I fix it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `this` before your second assignment of `val1`, so you're assigning to the local variable in the other branch, not the instance variable, hence the error that it is not always initialized. It should be

```
class myProps {
  public readonly val1: boolean;

  constructor(val1?: boolean) {
    val1 != undefined ? this.val1 = val1 : this.val1 = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in you constructor (specifically in your ternary operator assignment).

The assignment could be the following:

```js
class myProps {
  public readonly val1: boolean;

  constructor(val1?: boolean) {
    this.val1 = typeof val1 === 'boolean' ? !!val1 : true;
  }
}

var instance = new myProps(false);

console.log(instance.val1); //should print false, as passed parameter to constructor
```